# How to use method load() in loadable components using Java

Tags: java, python, selenium-webdriver

I have worked with loadable components using python were you could write a load method like the following:

```
def load(self):
   self._parent_page.get()
   self._parent_page.click_this_button()
```

Where click_this_button() is a method defined in the parent_page class

How can I use the same syntax in Java. In java I can only write parentPage.get(). Is there any way of accessing the methods defined in the parent as in Python?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean using super.function(), where the function is part of the inherited class?

Comment: Not really, the child function has no inheritance relation to the parent. The child uses parentPage.get() to use the two loadable components functions load and isloaded.